Oracle OEM13c Data Masking & subseting pack - Is it possible to create User defined relationship across multiple database in an Application Data Model
Using OEM 13c data masking pack. Can relationship be defined across multiple databases when creating application data model?
E.g. scenario:
Database_A (source), table_a, column_a is related to Database_B, table_b, column_b.
Desired outcome:
When database_a.table_a.column_a is masked, the same masking should also get applied to database_b.table_b.column_b automatically.
What I tried:
I can add user-defined relationship between columns within same application and same schema;
however, it does not work when trying to use multiple database or schema.
What is being done:
Multiple application defined in ADM that maps to different databases.

Created an ADM and associated two databases with the ADM.
Edit Application Data Model
Go to Tab "Referential Relationship" and click Add
Enter application (app_a mapped to database_a) and the object (table_a), under parent key on the left side.
Enter application (app_b mapped to database_b) and object (table_b), under Dependent key on right side.
Click on columns + icon under the parent key (left side)

It pops-up following error:

The application and object for both the parent key and the dependent key must be selected before adding key columns.



This was cross-checked with Oracle support and they confirmed that defining relationship across multiple applications/databases is not possible.
The error message it gives is confusing, perhaps Oracle should make it more relevant or best the dependent side should not list other databases then the ones on 'parent key' side.
